# What is the best way to lowercase, replace characters route with the route laravel helper?

Tags: laravel, replace, routes, lowercase

I want to *improve route generation*. Actually I am not satisfied with my solution and I am not on the best practice path.

I need to generate some route in blade.

- should generate only lowercase urls
- I will replace some letters like ä -> ae
- parse the date

What is the "best practice" for that?

I tried to do it directly in the blade file.

```php
@foreach($foods as $food)
            <a href="{{route('food.show', [
            'name' => $food->name,
            'date' => App\Models\Food::replaceCharacters(Str::lower(Carbon\Carbon::parse($food->urlDate)->isoFormat('DD-MMMM-YYYY')))])}}">
              Linkname}}
            </a>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel has some native helpers that can help you achieve this goal. The main is [`Str::slug`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-str-slug) method.

This is its source code:

```php
/**
 * Generate a URL friendly "slug" from a given string.
 *
 * @param  string  $title
 * @param  string  $separator
 * @param  string|null  $language
 * @return string
 */
public static function slug($title, $separator = '-', $language = 'en')
{
    $title = $language ? static::ascii($title, $language) : $title;

    // Convert all dashes/underscores into separator
    $flip = $separator === '-' ? '_' : '-';
    $title = preg_replace('!['.preg_quote($flip).']+!u', $separator, $title);

    // Replace @ with the word 'at'
    $title = str_replace('@', $separator.'at'.$separator, $title);

    // Remove all characters that are not the separator, letters, numbers, or whitespace.
    $title = preg_replace('![^'.preg_quote($separator).'\pL\pN\s]+!u', '', static::lower($title));

    // Replace all separator characters and whitespace by a single separator
    $title = preg_replace('!['.preg_quote($separator).'\s]+!u', $separator, $title);

    return trim($title, $separator);
}
```

This helper is enough to generate a SEO Friendly URL, but this answer only to the first and second bullet point. For the rest I think that the best solution is to use an [Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) in your `Food` class.

In this way, when you access the `name` property or the `urlDate` property you can receive an already formatted string. For example:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

[...]

public function getNameAttribute($value) 
{
   // Return the slug for a SEO friendly parameter
   return Str::slug($value);
}
```

Example input: `My äwe$oMe food|name`

Example output: `my-aweome-foodname`

For the date, you should only add to this code, the formatting part.

Comment: Thank you ||Gala the advice for an Accessor is a golden nugget for me. Everything works fine. :)

Comment: Glad to hear that :)